# Does Android have a system Python?

Tags: python

This is a random question. In a typical Android phone (say for example Pixel 6), is there an installation of CPython? I mean Python that's used internally by the system, rather than available to the user or through some third-party app.

If so, what version of Python?

Comment: No. Android uses Java. You can install Python in Termux app which provides a minimal Linux CLI environment on Android.